# provide custom namespace while configuring Alfresco LDAP integration

Tags: spring, ldap, alfresco

I have an Alfresco Community 5.2 installation with ldap-ad users/group syncrhonization and all works well.

Now I have to add an aspect with some properties and let ldap handle them, adding them to the cm:person.
So I have customized the `common-ldap-context.xml` as suggested [here](https://hub.alfresco.com/t5/alfresco-content-services-forum/is-this-possible-on-the-alfresco-6-0-community-edition-to/m-p/292332/highlight/false#M16188) but I've only managed it to work overriding the original Alfresco content model, using the cm: prefix as aspect/property namespace.

If I use my personal model prefix, whenever I start Alfresco up, I receive "unkown namespace" error from spring loading common-ldap-context.xml file.

How can I import my namespace into that file? Is it possible I have to use the cm: prefix necessarily?

Here is my common-ldap-context.xml fragment

```
<property name="personAttributeMapping">
    <map>
        <!-- ... -->
        <entry key="myc:prop1">
           <value>${ldap.synchronization.prop1</value>
        </entry>
        <entry key="myc:prop2">
            <value>${ldap.synchronization.prop2</value>
        </entry>
        <entry key="myc:prop3">
           <value>${ldap.synchronization.prop3</value>
        </entry>
        <entry key="myc:prop4">
            <value>${ldap.synchronization.prop4</value>
        </entry>
        <!-- ... -->
    </map>
</property>
```

The personAttributeMapping, inside common-ldap-context.xml, is placed in path `Alfresco/tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco/extension/Authentication/ldap-context.xml`. The custom document model is defined in bean component, loaded from in `bootstrap.context.xml`

Thanks.

Comment: I guess it's a problem of loading sequence during Alfresco bootstrap. How did you customize/deploy the personAttributeMapping and your custom document model containing the required aspect?

Comment: @HeikoRobert, How do you handle the loading sequence?

Comment: you are're right. I also just created a simple model and got the unkown namespace exception when initializing the spring bean.

Comment: How can we handle the bootstrap order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it working defining the required bean hint  `depends-on="..."` (of course using your bean name loading the model).

So my `custom-ldap-context.xml`in `extension/subsystems/Authentication/ldap-ad/ldap-ad1` (folder depends on your configured subsystem) looks like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC '-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN' 'http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd'>
<!--
   Bean definitions shared by the ldap and ldap-ad subsystems
-->

<beans>

   <!-- Regularly exports user and group information from LDAP -->

        <bean id="ecm4u.personDetails.dictionaryBootstrap" parent="dictionaryModelBootstrap" depends-on="dictionaryBootstrap">
                <property name="models">
                        <list>
                                <value>alfresco/extension/personDetails.xml</value>
                        </list>
                </property>
        </bean>

<bean id="userRegistry" class="org.alfresco.repo.security.sync.ldap.LDAPUserRegistry" depends-on="ecm4u.personDetails.dictionaryBootstrap">

<!-- snap -->

      <property name="personAttributeMapping">
         <map>

<!-- snap -->

           <!-- BEGIN New properties -->
            <entry key="pd:employeeNumber">
               <value>${ldap.synchronization.userEmployeeNumberAttributeName}</value>
            </entry>
            <!-- END New properties -->

<!-- snap -->
```